# Jquery confirm displays text several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery confirm dialog that takes some values and asks if we want to delete the records for them. The dialog box is prompted when I click a button. The problem is that if I simply close the dialog (not choosing nor Yes neither NO), the next time I open that dialog, it will display the message twice. If I do like this for a third time it displays it 3 times and so on ... Otherwise it works fine. But I want to fix this issue too.
Note: Several messages are displayed inside the same dialog box.

This is my code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                     $(".delete-button").click(function() {
                            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
                        var names = $row.find(".name").text(); // Find the name
                        var surname = $row.find(".surname").text(); // Find the surname  
                            $("#dialog").dialog({
                                autoOpen: false,
                                buttons : {
                                "Yes" : function() {
                                    $.ajax({  type: "POST",  url: "delete_lecturer.php", data: { x: names, y: surname}   })   //sends post query to delete the selected row
                                .done(function( msg ) {location.reload();})  //reloads page in order for the change to take become evident
                                    },"No" : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                            }
                            });
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                        $('<p>Are you sure you want to delete lecturer '+names+' '+surname+'?</p>').appendTo('#dialog');
                });
        });
</script>
```

And here I create the div for it:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Action can not be reversed!"></div>
```

Im not putting the message inside the div because i need to pass the values name and surname in the message. But I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: Clear the contents of `$("#dialog")` on each click, before you do anything else. - `$("#dialog").html('');`

Comment: OK, that was it. Please post it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the contents of `$("#dialog")` for each click, otherwise each click results in an additional paragraph being added to the div.

Change

```
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

to

```
 $("#dialog").html('').dialog("open");
```

or even

```
$("#dialog").html('<p>Are you sure you want to delete lecturer '+names+' '+surname+'?</p>').dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#dialog").empty().dialog("open");
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve when posting code.